# php and js: HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I meet a trouble that determine HTTP or HTTPS on my server via php and javascript.

I use javascript like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  alert(window.location.protocol);};
```

and it returns `https`

I use php like this:

```
echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')?'yes':'no';
```

and it echoes `no`

then, I try some other methods via php, but all of it cannot work well.

so  I want to know why is that.

My Server is nginx and apache (nginx is agent)

Answer (score 0):

From PHP documentation, $_SERVER['HTTPS'] is

> set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
>
> **Note**: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

So I think you may just check

```
echo (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off')?'yes':'no';
```

Comment: What is the value you get from $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Comment: It's undefine    ,,,,,,